# Command Prompt Compass compilation error

Tags: ruby

I am new to sencha touch. I have a error message while compiling **COMPASS COMPILE** in command prompt.

The following software are used:

1. `touch 2.3.1`
2. `ruby 2.0.0-p451`
   (`sass-3.4.5`)
   (`compass -0.12.2`)--updated version not working
3. `senchaCmd 4.0.2.67`

Change `app.scss` file to

```
@import 'sencha-touch/base';
@import 'sencha-touch/base/all'
```

then compile the `app.scss` file using command prompt. Compass compile shows the following error

```
C:\wamp\www\MyApp\resources\sass>compass compile c:/wamp/www/MyApp/resources/sas
s
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `r
equire': cannot load such file -- sass/script/node (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir
e.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass
_extensions/monkey_patches/browser_support.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir
e.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir
e.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass
_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass
_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass
_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir
e.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir
e.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass
_extensions.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir
e.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir
e.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:5
:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4
:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4
:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir
e.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir
e.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:20:i
n `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:8:in
 `fallback_load_path'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:19:i
n `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/compass:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
```

Please anyone guide me.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You did run bundle install, right?

Comment: Thanks BroiSatse...I got the answer, uninstall sass and reinstall sass version 3.2.18 it works fine......